# C# Copy one row from datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have problem with copying one row from my datagrid and then copy it.
For multiple selected rows it works fine as i want. But for one row not.

This is code for copy row

```
/// <summary>
    /// Method which will copy entire row.
    /// </summary>
    private void CopyRow(object obj)
    {
        var datagrid = obj as System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid;

        List<string> valsCollection = new List<string>();

        foreach (ENotifiedTruck item in datagrid.SelectedItems)
        {
            valsCollection.Add(item.ToStringLP());
        }

        var rows = GetDataGridRows(datagrid);
        int i1 = 0;
        foreach (DataGridRow r in rows)
        {
            DataGridColumn column = datagrid.Columns[0];

            TextBlock cellcontent = column.GetCellContent(r) as TextBlock;

            valsCollection[i1] = string.Format("{0}\t{1}", cellcontent.Text, valsCollection[i1]);
            i1++;

        }

        datagrid.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridClipboardCopyMode.IncludeHeader;
        valsCollection.Insert(0, string.Empty);
        ApplicationCommands.Copy.Execute(null, datagrid);
        string oldresult = (string)Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Text);

        List<string> rowCollection = new List<string>();
        rowCollection = oldresult.Split(new char[] { '\n' }).ToList<string>();

        if (rowCollection.Count == 0)
            return;

        string last = rowCollection[0];
        rowCollection = new List<string>();
        rowCollection.Add(last);
        rowCollection.AddRange(valsCollection);          

        oldresult = string.Join("\n", rowCollection);
        Clipboard.SetText($"{oldresult}");
    }


    public IEnumerable<DataGridRow> GetDataGridRows(System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid grid)
    {
        var itemsSource = grid.ItemsSource as IEnumerable;
        if (null == itemsSource) yield return null;
        foreach (var item in itemsSource)
        {
            var row = (DataGridRow)grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);
            if (null != row) yield return row;
        }
    }
```

Now in this particular line :

```
valsCollection[i1] = string.Format("{0}\t{1}", cellcontent.Text, valsCollection[i1]);
```

I got error when i select only one row.
This is the message i get from error: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll"

Any ideas? Thanks :]

Comment: Possibly where you adding values to valsCollection with the foreach statement. You use .SelectedItems, possibly this doesnt pick up one selected item so you are not adding anything to your collection and thus getting argument out of range when trying to get the a value out.

Comment: Sadly, i can´t iterate over datagrid.SelectedIndex. Maybe i just need new condition where i use only datagrid.SelectedIndex, but im not really sure.

Comment: Test out using SelectedIndex and see if that works, you dont need to iterate over it as its only one, only check if it is null, if it isnt then you can add it to your list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataGridRow has an Item property that should be the ENotifiedTruck you are trying to use.

You can use that instead of creating a separate collection beforehand.

Also, from what it looks like, you are getting all DataGridRow objects from GetDataGridRows based on the ItemsSource collection, while you are only creating entries in the valsCollection for selected rows.

If you have 1 selected row and 2 or more rows, then I think this should fail with an out of range exception when you get to [1] and valsCollection has no [1].

```
if(!datagrid.SelectedItems.Contains(r.Item))
    continue;
```

will skip any rows that aren't selected.